# Is this approach right of making a heatmap matrix

Tags: javascript, jquery, matrix, svg, d3.js

I need a heatmap matrix like this,

[image]

Now I tried using D3.js, I am able to make matrix and also made it zoomable too, but now I am stuck at adding Notes to rectangles as SVG doesn't supports it.

Am I on right track or can I use Div and jQuery instead to develop this heatmap, I visited hundreds of plugins but non satisfies my needs.

Proper matrix -  http://jsfiddle.net/nhe613kt/49/

Trying adding Notes with one rectangle - http://jsfiddle.net/nhe613kt/60

Can I use any other plugin or simple HTML ?

```
var width = 600,
height = 600;
var margin = {top: -5, right: -5, bottom: -5, left: -5};

var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1, 15])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);

var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                                    .attr("width", width)
                                    .attr("height", height)
                                    .style("background-color", "black")
                                    .append("g")
                                    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.right + ")")
                                    .call(zoom);

var zoomed = function () {
    svgContainer.attr("transform", "translate("+ d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
};

var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
.scaleExtent([1, 8])
.on("zoom", zoomed)
.size([width, height]);

svgContainer.call(zoom);

var rectangle1 = svgContainer.append("rect")
                            .attr("x", 0)
                            .attr("y", 0)
                            .attr("width", 100)
                            .attr("height", 100)
                            .attr("fill", "red")
                            .append("text")
                            .text("Hahaha");
```

Comment: SVG does support this, the text must be a sibling of the rect and not its child though.

Comment: How did you manage scales?? I am a heatmap . I am able to scale axis and rectangels of svg. But I cannot manage to scale axis with graph in appropriate ratio.

Comment: @Achilles I used viewbox for scaling and resizing

Comment: @Mathematics view box does work. Scales also remain in right proportion with graph. But is there a way I can limit the size of scales. scales should remain in proportion with graph but should not increase in size so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configure the `text` node properly:

```
svgContainer.append("text")
                        .attr("x", 10)
                        .attr("y", 20)
                        .attr("fill", "blue")
                        .text("Hahaha");
```

Otherwise, it might be outside of the visible are (y=0 is a common mistake; the Y coordinate moves the baseline of the text, not the top-right corner). Also without a color, the text will inherit one from the parent.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nhe613kt/65/

Comment: Thanks Aaron, I reached one of milestone, but as you know I want to make this a 16 rectangle matrix, how can I add text to specific rectangles

Comment: Figured out that I can change x and y to add it to other rectangles, thanks

Comment: That's one solution. The other is to put both the rect and the text into a group `<g>`. The position of the children of a group is relative to the group's top/left corner. That way, you could put the text always at the same offset and move the whole group around.